# Application crash: Method threw 'com.google.firebase.components.MissingDependencyException' exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)`, App crashes. Tried with enabling multidex. But no result. Can anyone help on this?

com.google.firebase.components.MissingDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency for component Component<[class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId]>{1, type=0, deps=[Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.events.Subscriber, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsApi, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.platforminfo.UserAgentPublisher, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.heartbeatinfo.HeartBeatInfo, type=required, direct=true}]}: interface com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsApi

Dependency used: `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.3'`

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you managed to find the issue? I can't figure out why I'm missing dependencies as I'm including all libraries I need.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and it looks like something messed with the manifest, when I create a test app in Android Studio and get the required services/providers from there in that order all starting work fine. Here the working manifest Application section for FCM (firebase-common-19.5.0, firebase-iid-21.0.1, firebase-messaging-21.0.1 and all dependencies):

```
 <!-- AndroidPushApplicationManifest.xml -->
    <service android:name="${ApplicationID}.MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/pn_icon"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/notification_channel_id"/>    

    <!--
         FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
         but set to not exported to explicitly avoid allowing another app to call it.
    -->
    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        <!--
            This registrar is not defined in the dynamic-module-support sdk itself to allow non-firebase
            clients to use it as well, by defining this registrar in their own core/common library.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.dynamicloading.DynamicLoadingRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.backends.TransportBackendDiscovery"
        android:exported="false" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="backend:com.google.android.datatransport.cct.CctBackendFactory"
            android:value="cct" />
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="${ApplicationID}.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:initOrder="100" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" >
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" />
```